# Syntax error in python 2.7 with aws cli command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-2.7, jenkins, ubuntu-16.04

we started to getting next error :

```
+ aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
        import awscli.clidriver   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 17, in <module>
        import botocore.session   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 30, in <module>
        import botocore.credentials   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 34, in <module>
        from botocore.config import Config   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/config.py", line 16, in <module>
        from botocore.endpoint import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, MAX_POOL_CONNECTIONS   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 22, in <module>
        from botocore.awsrequest import create_request_object   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 26, in <module>
        import botocore.utils   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 33, in <module>
        import botocore.httpsession   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 38, in <module>
        from certifi import where   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .core import contents, where   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/core.py", line 17
        def where() -> str:
                    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Its running on jenkins slave with ubuntu 16 with default python of 2.7 and python 3.5.2
Maybe someone encountered ?

Comment: `-> str` is a return type annotation, a relatively new feature that is not supported in Python 2.7.x, which has been EOL for a while now. Please upgrade your version of Python.

Comment: Cool, can you please suggest to which version maybe? And maybe you know if aws cli using python from env or embedded?

Comment: Which version of the awscli is this? It sounds back-level. The awscli now ships with an included Python runtime so it doesn't depend on an external version.

Comment: FYI I was referring to [awscli v2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-cli-v2-is-now-generally-available/), which includes the Python runtime.

Comment: 1.19.50 aws cli version

Answer (score 0):

so we solved by upgrading ami from Ubuntu xenial 16.04 to 20 , so this way python that came with this version was already most updated and it solved our issue. Attempt of updating python on xenial 16.04 was not so successful due to 16.04 is on end life and everything is deprecated for this versions including deadsnakes ppa.